# What config option allows bot to respond to commands posted by itself?

Tags: errbot

If I have en external process post a message as bot, let's say `!help` how can make Errbot respond to it? Currently it ignores messages coming from errbot itself. I could not find a configuration option for this.

Answer (score 0):

Good question: It is in the contract of each backend to detect and filter out the messages coming from the bot itself.
This design choice is mainly to avoid weird infinite loop behavior etc.

In general if the bot emits something and needs to react from it, why not doing that at that point instead of waiting for its own response?